# How to "diff" effective/computed css rules of an HTML element from two different pages?

Tags: css, diff

I've come across this problem enough times that I'd like to find a smarter approach. The scenario is that I make changes to a web app, and an element on the page ends up looking different than it used to look and I'm not sure why. Sometimes it's because I've refactored markup and css, or sometimes because I've added a new css include on the page, or other reasons.

Sometimes the css looks to be pretty much the same, and so I have to go an elaborate hunt in the browser dev tools for what css rules have been applied. If I can't spot the cause in the "properties" section of Chrome's dev tools, I look at the "Computed Style" section. Sometimes I still have trouble spotting the difference, so I paste the "Computed Style" section for the broken and working versions into text files, save to disk and then diff the two. It ends up being something frustrating, like the element in the broken version inherited a different line-height from an ancestor element.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Could you give an example of the visual changes? Isn't it trivial to determine which property changed from looking at the page? (E.g. if the element's margins are bigger, it's `margin`, if the font looks different, it's one of the `font-` or `text-` properties, etc.) From merely comparing the page's visual appearance before/after, you should be able to determine which properties changed.

Comment: Most of the time it is trivial, yes, but not always. I don't have an example right now, I should have posted this question the last time I came across this problem. It often involves inheriting rules from a parent element, but tracking down which parent isn't obvious.

Comment: Well, the browser's dev tools *do* give you a list of all the inherited properties, so you could load up both states of the page in two separate browser windows, and then select the same element in both dev tools, and compare the inheritance information of both. CSS inheritance can be a pain if it becomes too complex (e.g. inherited properties canceling out other inherited properties), so consider dealing with that directly, by refactoring the CSS code in order to reduce the complexity.

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? I have a designer that made changes to a library's CSS file right in the file, making future upgrading hard.

It is possible to determine the changes by site but it's a painstaking process if the changes are vast.